# $(X,d)$ separable implies uniformly equicontinuous subset of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ is separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, separable-spaces, arzela-ascoli

I'm trying to prove a certain class of subsets of $C(X)$ (made into a metric space, equipped with the sup-norm) are separable iff $X$ is (where $X$ is a metric space) and while one direction is easy, it's much tougher to prove that the subset of $C(X)$ is separable if $X$ is.

I have taken a basic course in topology and read a fair amount, so I've been trying to use/generalise a version of Arzela-Ascoli (which assumes $X$ is compact and various other stronger conditions) that we proved in the course. In particular, I know that the subspaces of $C(X)$ I'm considering are uniformly equicontinuous (indeed they are 1-Lipschitz) and I was hoping that this would be enough to deduce separability of the subset.

I know there are a few steps in typical Arzela-Ascoli-type proofs:

1. You require the input space to be separable to get a countable dense subset *(and this is what we are assuming!)*.
2. You show that given some (uniformly) bounded sequence of functions has a "diagonal" subsequence such that the members' outputs converge on the dense subset *(this makes no assumptions on $X$)*.
3. You show that if $(f_n)$ is uniformly equicontinuous and converges on the dense set, then it converges in the maximum norm to some $f$. *(The proof I know only uses $X$ being totally bounded for this step.)*
4. You put this altogether, along with maybe some fact like compact iff closed and totally bounded, to deduce your Arzela-Ascoli.

**I'm not really sure how to adjust steps 3 and 4 to deduce separability...**

EDIT:

I've found an essentially unrelated argument which directly shows that if $S\subseteq C(X)$ is bounded and uniformly equicontinuous and $X$ is *totally bounded*, then $S$ is totally bounded. This is almost but not quite what I want!

Comment: What topology do you consider on $C(X)$?

Comment: @Jochen: sorry I didn't originally explain that! I've added in the text that I'm considering the topology induced by the sup-metric on $C(X)$. I've read that things like the compact-convergence topology can be easier to work with in the case where $X$ is non-compact but it's important for my application that we remain as "metric" as possible.

Comment: @Jochen: though if you know of any useful results assuming a different topology, like the compact-open or compact-convergence topologies, I'd be interested in hearing them.

Comment: So the result from your edit isn't satisfactory because of which assumption? Total boundedness of $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit mysterious so I don't precisely know what are your assumptions on the subspace. Nevertheless I think it isn't true.

**Counterexample**
Let $X=[0,\infty)$. It's separable. For any $c\in C:=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ there is a $1$-Lipschitz function $f_c\in C(X)$ such that $f_c(n)=c(n)$. Observe that if $c_1\neq c_2$ then $\|f_{c_1}-f_{c_2}\|_{\sup}\geq 1$. Then $F=\{f_c:c\in C\}$ is an uncountable discrete subset of $C(X)$. Therefore it isn't separable.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. The point was that the assumption of total boundedness of $X$ was stronger than I had hoped for and this is a counterexample to the claim I was trying to test out. Apologies for not being clear. The problems anyway are even deeper than I initially realised: in general $X$ even being totally bounded is not enough to guarantee $C(X)$ is even a metric space under the sup-norm!